# I am working on vb.net and basic thing which I am doing is Deposit and withdraw of amounts

Tags: vb.net

```
So  If txtFirstName.Text = String.Empty And
        txtLastName.Text = String.Empty And
        txtAmount.Text = String.Empty Then
    MsgBox("Please enter Information")
```

this part doesnt work at all, when i tried keeping the breakpoint and look at how it is working, It came out true but the msgbox was never shown.
and the deposit and withdraw functions work as strings.
Also I want to know How I can keep my code in different class and use it in this class for deposit and withdraw buttons.
Here is the code that I wrote:

```
    Option Strict On
    Option Explicit On

    Public Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
           if not IsPostBack then
             lblFirstName.Focus()
        End Sub

        Protected Sub btnConfirm_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
            If txtFirstName.Text = String.Empty And
                    txtLastName.Text = String.Empty And
                    txtAmount.Text = String.Empty Then
                MsgBox("Please enter Information")
            Else
                doConfirm()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub doConfirm()
            If rbtndeposit.Checked Then
                txtBalance.Text += (txtAmount.Text)
            ElseIf rbtnWithdraw.Checked Then
              if txtAmount.text <= txtBalance.text then
                txtBalance.text -= txtAmount.text
             else
                msgBox("Funds not sufficient") 
            End If
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,Your logic with your text input is a bit flawed, the AND should be OrElse:

```
Protected Sub btnConfirm_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click

        If txtFirstName.Text.Length < 1 OrElse _
                txtLastName.Text.Length < 1 OrElse _
                txtAmount.Text.Length < 1 Then

            MsgBox("Please enter Information")

        Else

            doConfirm()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Secondly, you are trying to do mathematical calculations with text values.  Convert your input to the correct data type when doing calculations.

```
    Private Sub doConfirm()

        If rbtndeposit.Checked Then

           txtBalance.Text = Cstr(Cdbl(txtBalance.Text) + Cdbl(txtAmount.Text))

        ElseIf rbtnWithdraw.Checked Then

            If CDbl(txtAmount.text) <= Cdbl(txtBalance.text) Then

               txtBalance.text = Cstr(Cdbl(txtBalance.text) - Cdbl(txtAmount.text))

            Else

                msgBox("Funds not sufficient") 

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

You should how ever use tryparse to check if the input for the amount is valid or your code will crash when the input is not valid, for example:

```
 Dim amount As Double

 If Double.TryParse(txtAmount.text, amount) Then

    If rbtndeposit.Checked Then

        txtBalance.Text = Cstr(Cdbl(txtBalance.Text) + amount)

    ElseIf rbtnWithdraw.Checked Then

        If amount <= Cdbl(txtBalance.text) then

            txtBalance.text = Cstr(Cdbl(txtBalance.text) - amount)

        else

            msgBox("Funds not sufficient") 

        End If

    End If

 Else

   MessageBox.Show("Invalid amount entered.")


 End if
```

As for storing your procedure is a separate class,  I think just creating functions should be sufficient:

```
Private Sub Button1_WithDraw(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_WithDraw.Click

    txtBalance.Text = Withdraw(CDbl(txtAmount.Text), Cdbl(txtBalance.text)).ToString

End Sub

Private Function Withdraw(ByVal Amount As Double, ByVal Balance As Double) As Double

    Balance = Balance - Amount

    Return Balance

End Function
```

Comment: I tried to convert it into double but it throws exception that string cannot be parsed to double.

Comment: That means the value entered is in the wrong format.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks